# Why won't my website use the Tahoma font?

Tags: css, fonts

I have my fonts set in my style.css:

```
font-family: "Arial, Verdana, sans-serif";
```

But my website still seems to use sans serif. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commas in your CSS font-family specification need to be outside the quotes.

For example:

```
font-family: "Arial", "Verdana", sans-serif; /* And you should really 
omit the quotes if it's only one word */
```

Not

```
font-family: "Arial, Verdana, sans-serif";
```

Otherwise, the CSS parser thinks you're looking for a font called "Arial, Verdana, sans-serif", which clearly doesn't exist.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "you should really omit the quotes if it's only one word."

Answer (score 3):

Try removing your "" from the font-family definition:

```
font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
```

Like that. Only put the " around when you have multiple words such as

```
font-family: "mutiple word font name",tahoma, sans-serif;
```